# Asymptotics in algorithms

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

In nearly every algorithm analysis that I've seen, the runtime is some composition or product of elementary functions such as:

- $p(x)$ where $p$ is a polynomial
- $\log(x)$
- $e^x$
- constants $c\in\mathbb{R}$

For example, $n! \sim \sqrt{n}\cdot e^{n\log n}$.

Can anyone either (1) give me a counterexample to my observation, or (2) formalize my observation in the sense of a theorem which might sound something like: compositions and products of the above classes of functions form a dense subset of all possible algorithmic runtimes?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define "algorithmic runtime"? What is your computational model?

Comment: This was just an offhand thought, so I don't have a computational model in mind. Mostly, I was wondering if this has already been studied, and if so, I'd like to know the results.

Comment: My point is that it cannot be studied without being formalized :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Ackermann-type running times. For example, any algorithm that depends on the number of parts in the $\epsilon$-regular partition of Szemerédi's regularity lemma will take time that can be expressed as an exponential tower of $2$s, with height depending on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you, let’s add that to the list.

Comment: Inverse Ackermann and log-* make an appearance as well, for instance in best-known algorithms for minimum spanning tree.

Comment: The issue here is that no matter what the new complexity is suggested, you'll just "add it to the list." But since you don't have a well-defined computation model to begin with, there is no end to that list, and it's not possible to argue formally and prove things until you do explain what you mean by "algorithmic runtime," @klein4